# Odd error calling SQLCommand.ExecuteReader() from powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, ado.net, sqlcommand

What does Powershell error below mean when you are calling `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`?

> System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException: The
>   argument "+" does not belong to the set
>   "unicode,utf7,utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified
>   by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set
>   and then try the command again. at
>   System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute.ValidateElement(Object
>   element) at
>   System.Management.Automation.ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute.Validate(Object
>   arguments, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics) at
>   System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal
>   parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata,
>   ParameterBindingFlags flags)

(answer to follow immediately; I just wanted to share my debugging experience because I couldn't find it)

Answer (score 2):

The text of the query included a 'GO' statement.  There's some sort of security filtering going on, and it is considered an encoding issue.

Just an FYI for me or the universe if that kinda thing happens again.  Four hours of my life I wish I'd been able to Google away.